# Drupal 7 - Detect if render($page['content']) contains specific content type

Tags: php, drupal

Noob junior here so apologies if this is basic and can't be done. I would, in the interest of developing my knowledge love feedback :)

Lets say I have a basic page:

```
1   <section>
2       <div class="container">
3           <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
4       </div>
5   </section>
```

In the rendered content there is a content type called 'fifty-fifty' which outputs:

```
<div class="fifty_fifty_banner">
    <div class="half">
        left
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need is for pages with that "fifty fifty" banner in to have a full width container and for other pages to have 960px width container.

In the first block of code, I would like line 2 to contain an if statement or some check that adds a class if it does, possible?

## Edit 1:

Tried `if(array_key_exists())` AND `if(in_array())` on two pages, one with and one without the fifty fifty banner.

`array_key_exists()` returns false on both pages.

`if(in_array())` returns true on both pages

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify your question?. I mean, do you have a drupal content type called fifty fifty?.  And do you want to change the width class container for those other content types?.

Comment: @Daniela - Hey there. Thanks for the reply. So, I'm a noob and will try my best to explain. If I go to structure > content types there is a list of content types. One of those is called "Flexible Page Survey". If I edit a Flexible Page Survey I can add in a little block called "Fifty Fifty Banner". That will output that specific block onto any of the pages that are "Flexible Page Survey". Where the content for those is rendered in the `render($page['content']);` (which is in page.tpl.php) I want to add a class to the parent container. I just want to check if that page is displaying it.

Comment: I added you an answer where you ask for the content type in your page.tpl.php file. I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like this in your page.tpl.php file, to add a class for the Flexible Page Survey content type:

```
if ($variables['node']->type == 'content_type_machine_name' && isset($variables['node']->field_paragraph_name)) {
  ?>
  <div class="add-your-class-here">

  </div>
  <?php

}
?>
```

/admin/structure/types/manage/content_type_machine_name/fields

This will be your  field_paragraph_name

[image]

Comment: I tried `if ($variables['node']->type == "fifty_fifty_banner") {echo "YES";} else {echo "NO"; }` and got the response `NO`

Comment: I got the fifty fifty banner machine name from: `admin/structure/paragraphs`

Comment: @Mark, you should see the machine name here: /admin/structure/types the machine name you need is for the Flexible Page Survey  content type.

Comment: It is not in the list. It is a paragraph bundle that is added to a type. It is not a type itself.

Comment: Ok. Please correct me if I'm wrong or not, you said you are adding that paragraph to this content type: Flexible Page Survey, rigth?. So, all pages from that content type will contain that banner?. Isn't it?. In that case, the code should works. If you want to make sure the paragraphs is there, please debug this variable: $variables['node']

Comment: I will give it a debug

Comment: @Mark, I debugged, I think you have 2 options  ask for the content type or for the field name which is the paragraphs in your content type:  $variables['node']->field_paragraph_name. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @daniela - I tried that but can't see the fifty fifty banner in the page. Fifty Fifty banner can be found `structure > paragraph bundles`

Comment: @Mark, you need to follow the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do any of the conditional work in the template itself.

Do the business logic in `hook_preprocess_page()` of `template.php` and simply modify the classes of the render block/html if the content type has the format you want in the soon-to-be-render render arrays.

Comment: Yes, he can do that, but the logic will be the same asking for the content type and the field_name.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is install the [Context module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context). Steps as follows:

1.) Create a new context and set the node type to your content type under the Conditions
[image]
2.) Create a reaction and set it to theme html and give your body a class
[image]
3.) Style your css based off of said class off the body tag.